# Do large and small derived categories of algebraic variety determine each other?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a projective variety. I wonder whether the derived categories $D(QCoh\,X)$ and $D^b(Coh\,X)$ somehow determine each other. For example, if there is a full exceptional collection $D^b(Coh\,X)=\left< E_1, \ldots E_n\right>$, where $E_i=D^b(Coh\,pt)$, is there an analogous decomposition for $D(QCoh\,X)$?